# Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined, in web application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firebase

I am facing a weird problem in my web application. Actually I am using Firebase has hosting and I am trying to create a "logout" button in my webpage. I am saying this weird because the JavaScript file named "login.js" I wrote the function for login is working correctly. But for logout function, it is saying, "Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined".

Here I am posting the script I wrote for-

HTML-

```
<div class="subSetingOptionList">
    <button onclick="logOut()">Logout</button>
  </div>
```

JavaScript-

```
// ON AUTH STATE CHANGES

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {

        // USER IS SIGNED IN
      document.getElementById("showIfNotLogIn").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("onUserLogin").style.display = "block";
        } else {
      // No user is signed in.
      document.getElementById("showIfNotLogIn").style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById("onUserLogin").style.display = "none";
    }
  });

  //THIS PART IS WORKING FOR SURE

function letMeLogin(){


let usernaming = document.getElementById("userNameForLogin").value;
let userpasswording = document.getElementById("userPasswordForLogin").value;

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(usernaming, userpasswording).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...

    window.alert(`Alert: ${errorMessage}`);
  });

}

//THIS IS THE PART FOR LOGOUT WHICH IS GIVING THE ERROR

    function logOut(){

  firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
      // Sign-out successful.
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // An error happened.
   });
  }
```

Comment: Have you included firebase web key in your project?

Comment: yes, it's not the main "index.html" page, so i didn't included the key in this page

Comment: Are you sure you're on the same page as login and you didn't navigated to different page that don't have firebase.js included?

Comment: @jcubic I AM on different page

Comment: If you're on different page then you need to include firebase.js also on that page (using script tag) script files don't travel from one page to the other, whole browser session is cleared when you navigate to other page.

Comment: @jcubic hey man, please can you give me the example, I will be grateful to you

Comment: check docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup each page that use the api need to have same setup <script tag with firebase.js file and API key and all that stuff.

Comment: getting the same error, but, using the Browserify can be helpful?

Comment: isn't there any one who can help me